# Loading a Select List from an Array with spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to read in a text file with a list of options in it.  The file contains entries like those below:

```
"11-11 ALL DAYS           "  
"24 HRS                   "  
"4-11 ALL DAYS            "  
"4-11 M-F 6-11 SA-SU      "  
"4-11:15 M-F 6-11:15 SA-SU"
```

As you can see I have to deal with quotes and a lot of spaces.  My code below reads in the array and will alert the values just fine.  When it goes to append the options I create it ends up giving me an option for every single character.  I'm not sure what is going on as this is my first attempt at doing something like this.  Any ideas are appreciated

```
        var data = [];
        var option = '';

        $.get('Hours_Strings.txt', function (data) {
            alert(data);

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                option += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
            };
            $('#iSelectHours').append(option);


        }, 'text');        
    }
```

Comment: You need to split data up into an array of lines.

Comment: What happens when use `console.log(data)` in your `get` method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every option is on a new line in your text file, you can do something like this:

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
    //code here using lines[i] which will give you each line
   //You can remove the quotes in here as well or keep them if you need them.
}
```

Comment: That did it!  Thanks for the help. Should've thought about that since I've actually split arrays before......

Answer (score 0):

Well, your `data` from request must be splitted by newline `\n`

```
$(function(){
   var data=[], dataOpt = [], option = '';
   data.push("\"11-11 ALL DAYS\"");
    data.push("\"24 HRS\"");

   $.get('Hours_Strings.txt', function (data) {
        console.log(data.split('\n')); //split here by newline
       dataOpt = data.split('\n');

            for (i = 0; i < dataOpt.length; i++) {
                option += '<option value="' + dataOpt[i] + '">' + dataOpt[i] + '</option>';
            };
            $('#iSelectHours').append(option);


        }, 'text'); 
});
```

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EgBDD/) for you

Answer (score 0):

```
            var allData = [];
            var option = '';

            $.get('Hours_Strings.txt', function(allData) {
                var dataLines = allData.split("\n");
                for (i = 0; i < dataLines.length; i++) {
                    var dataLine = dataLines[i].replace(/\"/g,"");
                    option += '<option value="' + dataLine + '">' + dataLine + '</option>';
                }
                $('#iSelectHours').append(option);
            }, 'text');
```